# Blackberry HTTP POST problem

Tags: http, blackberry, post, httpconnection

I have a problem with sending POST to server from blackberry (I currently trying on simulator). The problem is, the POST data isn't send to server.

I know there are lot of topics about this, but I'va tried many of them but still I can't make it work.

Here is the code I use in the blackberry

```
        hc = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(Params.URL_TTS_GET, Connector.READ_WRITE);

        //Prepare post
        URLEncodedPostData p = new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false);
        p.append("ttsid", "" + header.id);
        byte[] data = p.getBytes();
        String ss = new String(data);
        hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        hc.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, p.getContentType());
        hc.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_CONTENT_LENGTH, Integer.toString(data.length));
        OutputStream os = hc.openOutputStream();
        os.write(data);
        os.close();
```

I also tried this :

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
hc = (HttpConnection)cf.getConnection(Params.URL_TTS_GET).getConnection();
```

But  got 301 (Moved permanently) response for unknown reason.

any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried using the URL that the 301 points to?

Comment: The strange thing is that 301 redirects to the exactly same URL of my request. And also, I'm testing in localhost.

Comment: No differences, like a www. added or removed?